# Show JDialog ("Please Wait") on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have a `JFrame` and this `JFrame` has a `JButton`.

I want in `JButton` first show `JDialog` (display `"Please wait"`) and execute other code then closing `JDialog`.

But when showing `JDialog` stopped to execute other code on `JButton`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start the other processing on a `Thread` (e.g. in a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)) and at the start of it, call `modalDialog.setVisible(true)`.  At the end of the task call `setVisible(false)`.

Comment: Some additional effort would be required to not make the user close the 'please wait' dialog - otherwise the button would be accessible to start another swingworker.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest creating a simple JDialog and then disposing it after your code has run. You can create your JDialog with the following code:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Please wait...");
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
dialog.add(label);
dialog.pack();
```

And implement it like this:

```
dialog.setVisible(true); // show the dialog on the screen

        // Do something here

dialog.setVisible(false); // set visibility to false when the code has run
```

Comment: IMHO, this is the best answer.  Why add the extra complication of threads if they're not required.

Comment: This is simple, but may not work in some cases... `javax.swing` takes a hell of a time to create or paint a frame. So your message might not be visible as the JVM does not wait until swing finishes its work. The thread might move on to `//Do something here`.

Comment: The 'do something here' executes on the EDT. You must free up the EDT to get to see the wait dialog at all.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the jdialog is in modal mode, try change the modal property of the jdialog : `yordialog.setModal(false)`.

Answer (score 2):

It stopped because you are using the "MAIN-Thread" which is used to execute the code and show the JDialog.

To solve this you should look into something like [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html)